# save bash output and error message to log file within the script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to redirect stdout to log file within the script using following code:

```
LOGFILE=logfile.txt
exec 2> $LOGFILE
```

But the logfile.txt is empty. Could anyone give me some hint?

Comment: did you try directing to the logfile without using a variable?
ex: `exec &> logfile.txt` should begin redirect to stdout&sderr

Answer (score 0):

The redirect notation `2>` means to redirect fd 2, which is stderr, not stdout.

If you want to use stdout, write

```
exec >$LOGFILE
```

If you want both

```
exec >$LOGFILE 2>&1
```

Comment: I tried both of them. But i still get empty log file.

Comment: try setting `$LOGFILE` to an absolute path, instead of relative- perhaps you are creating it, just not where you want it

Comment: I assume that later in the shell script you're producing some output, right?